# What does CommandLineRunner do in this case?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm completely new to Spring & not very experienced in Java admittedly. I am trying to go through the [Building REST services with Spring](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) tutorial on the spring.io website. I came across the following code segment and I'm confused as to what it actually does.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(AccountRepository accountRepository,
            BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository) {
        return (evt) -> Arrays.asList(
                "jhoeller,dsyer,pwebb,ogierke,rwinch,mfisher,mpollack,jlong".split(","))
                .forEach(
                        a -> {
                            Account account = accountRepository.save(new Account(a,
                                    "password"));
                            bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account,
                                    "http://bookmark.com/1/" + a, "A description"));
                            bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account,
                                    "http://bookmark.com/2/" + a, "A description"));
                        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I looked up CommandLineRunner on Spring Boot docs, and it says it's an interface that gets implemented if you want to execute some code when the application starts. But to my limited knowledge, CommandLineRunner is not getting implemented by anything in the above code segment. Also, I have no clue where the init() method came from or what it really is.

Additionally, I downloaded the complete code from their [github repo](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-bookmarks.git) but I'm not quite sure how to actually run it. I read earlier today that `SpringApplication.run()` makes it so that you don't have to deploy anything to an external service like Tomcat. But when I tried `java -jar ./jarFileName` for the Application class (seemed like a natural choice since it had main() ), it gave an error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question:

CommandLineRunner is getting implemented by the Lambda expression:

```
return (evt) -> Arrays.asList(...
```

Second thing, the `init()` method is a Spring Bean definition, as indicated by the `@Bean` annotation.

And third, the way of running the application you got right. `java -jar jarFile` should run it. I looked at the modules in the git repo and some of the modules are missing the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` configuration that makes the jars executable. But you can run them from the command line like this: `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: You are saying `CommandLineRunner` is being implemented by lambda but i don't see any run method implemented in there and why are we returning `CommandLineRunner` ? @Ulises